# Calculate the 2D Fourier transform of an Image

Tags: image-processing, image, fourier-analysis

I am new to *Mathematica*, and using version 8.0.

I would like to calculate the 2D Fourier Transform of an `Image` with *Mathematica* and plot the magnitude and phase spectrum, as well as reconstruct the image with the inverse transform.

Comment: Hello. You do not have to sign in post, you only need to update your profile data and we can see it on miniature. Also, it is good to show some research effort and minimal sample of data (image) you are working with.

Comment: How about reading the documentation, like that on the [Fourier function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fourier.html)?

Comment: Coming from another language its not clear at all that you need to convert your imagedata to (?image-)data (other than just loading it) before doing DFT. I got stuck for hours on this as well. The question and its answer are useful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 37):

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
Image[img, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = ImageData[img];(*get data*)
{nRow, nCol, nChannel} = Dimensions[data];
d = data[[All, All, 2]];
d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
fw = Fourier[d, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];

(*adjust for better viewing as needed*)
fudgeFactor = 100;
abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw];
Labeled[Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 300],Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
arg = Arg@fw;
Labeled[Image[arg/Max[arg], ImageSize -> 300],Style["Phase spectrum", 18]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I do think Ms. Lena looks prettier in the spatial domain than in the frequency domain.

Comment: I think OP wants to reconstruct the image from spectrum.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help.... Is there not a direct command of 2D DFT in MMA as 1D DFT in MMA????

Comment: Nice answer. Very basic question that requires knowledge of some differences between _Mathematica_ and other languages. Im glad you gave him such a complete answer, it helped me too. And plus one for the PS!

Comment: I have [post a question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/how-to-reconstruct-a-image-from-spectrum) about your solution's extend.If you are available,help me please.

Comment: In your answer, I did not understand the need for line
    d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}]; 
Could you comment on that? Also, are you computing the DFT only for the green color? Why did you pick this one?

Answer (score 19):

Taking the Fourier transform is easy and fun!

Let's strip away some of the complexities. First, remove the color from the image, since this just complicates things (you can always take the transform of each color channel separately).

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], "Grayscale"];
```

Here are the magnitude and phase of the Fourier transform:

```
(abs = Abs[Fourier[ImageData[img]]]) // Image
(arg = Arg[Fourier[ImageData[img]]]) // Image
```

[image]

[image]

To invert these, use:

```
Chop[InverseFourier[(abs E^(I arg))]] // Image
```

[image]

which is the same as we started with. The `Chop` is needed because spurious (almost zero) complex numbers remain after the Inverse).

Notice how clear and concise this is... it's just taking `Fourier` of the image, taking the Abs and Arg to get the magnitude and phase images, and then reconstructing using `InverseFourier` on `Abs*Exp[I Arg]`.

This is a bit simpler than usual. For one thing, the zero frequency is in the upper left hand corner (instead of the center, where one usually plots it). You can move this to the center using `RotateLeft` on the transformed image, or by multiplying in the spatial domain by `+/-1^(i,j)` as in Nasser's answer. Of course, then, to reconstruct, you have to rotate back. This also uses the default `FourierParameters`, which may or may not be exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 for stripping all superfluous distraction away, and zeroing in on the essence of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Mathematica also has a builtin function called [`ImagePeriodogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePeriodogram.html) that returns an `Image` representing the power spectrum of the image. This won't help with phase spectra or reconstructing images, however.