# Using 2D Fourier transform of an image to detect typical wavelengths

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

I am new to Mathematica, and I have read this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29203/determine-the-2d-fourier-transform-of-an-image) to understand how to perform Fourier transform on an image. My mission is to extract information on the typical distance between the black patches in the image I have attached here. The code that I attach here gives me the Fourier transform, but I don't know how to take out from the Fourier transform the values of the wavenumbers.

I have used this piece of code

```
img = Import["example.jpg"];
Image[img, ImageSize -> 300]

data = ImageData[img];(*get data*)
{nRow, nCol, nChannel} = Dimensions[data];
d = data[[All, All, 2]];
d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
fw = Fourier[d, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];

(*adjust for better viewing as needed*)
fudgeFactor = 100;
abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw];
Labeled[Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 300],Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]]
```

I have the following image on which I would like to perform this analysis - [image]

Comment: `fw` contains the values. I.e. `fw[[1,1]]` is the value for frequency 0/0, `fw[[1,2]]` is the value for frequency 0/1...

Comment: What nikie says. You'd probably want to leave out the line `d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];` which seems to apply some checkerboard pattern to the white background pixels.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries is right, I didn't notice that. IIRC, this is done to "rotate" the 0 frequencies to the center of the FFT output. If you want to interpret the values numerically (instead of displaying the FT as a picture), you'd want to remove that line.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like random blobs, and that's what the FFT suggests...

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hALsH.jpg"];
imgBW = ImageData@ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
imgZ = imgBW - Mean@Mean[imgBW]; 
xf = Abs[Fourier[imgZ, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]];
{d1, d2} = Ceiling[Dimensions[xf]/2];
xCentered = RotateLeft[xf, {d1, d2}];
ArrayPlot[xCentered]
```

[image]

Here we zoom into the center where we can see it looks a lot like a randomized Gaussian blob:

```
zoom = 50; 
ArrayPlot[xCentered, PlotRange -> {{d1 - zoom, d1 + zoom}, {d2 - zoom, d2 + zoom}}]
```

[image]

I think this means you are going to have to approach this a different way.

Comment: If I squint I see the letter S in the zoomed center

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer more of an extended comment...

> My mission is to extract information on the typical distance between
>   the black patches in the image I have attached here.

Do we have to use Fourier transform for this?

For example we can get the required estimate with these commands:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hALsH.jpg"];
Row[{"Image dimensions:", ImageDimensions[img]}]
imgB = ColorNegate@Binarize[img, 0.4];
Block[{img = imgB}, 
 Show[img, 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
    Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
     ComponentMeasurements[
       img, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]]}]]
 ]
```

[image]

```
comps = ComponentMeasurements[
    imgB, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]];

dists = Flatten@
   Map[Take[Sort[#], UpTo[5]] &, 
    Outer[EuclideanDistance[#1[[1]], #2[[1]]] - (#1[[2]] + #2[[2]]) &,
      comps, comps, 1]];

qs = Range[0, 1, 0.25];
TableForm[{qs, Quantile[dists, qs]}]

Histogram[dists]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to locate the black components and then measure some properties of them. Here we locate them using `MorphologicalComponents`, find the centroids using `ComponentMeasurements` and then calculate the distance between the centroids using `Nearest`.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hALsH.jpg"];
imgBW = Binarize@ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
comp = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[Dilation[imgBW, 5]]] // Colorize
cent = ComponentMeasurements[comp, "Centroid"]; 
allNears = Nearest[cent[[All, 2]], #, 2] & /@ cent[[All, 2]];
Total[Norm[allNears[[#, 1]] - allNears[[#, 2]]] & /@ 
      Range[Length[allNears]]]/Length[allNears]
```

As you can see, the average distance form the center of each blob to the nearest adjacent blob is about 33 pixels.

[image]

Comment: Basically very similar to my answer (+1, btw). I do like the application of `Nearest` and `Dilation`. (A minor point, I think using `Mean`/`Median` might be better than using `Total[_]/Length[_]`.

Comment: @Anton -- after I finished the Fourier answer, I worked out the morphological approach - by the time I finished, you had already posted... so +1 to you for beating me!

Comment: I think you should combine your FFT answer with this one. From my perspective, after applying FFT and concluding non-regularity the next natural thing to do is to apply the morphological components approach.