# How to do the Fourier transform of a picture?

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, optics

I want to generate Fourier transforms of a picture. the transform can represent the diffraction pattern of the picture.

Basically, if I have a picture. Then, the result should look like this:

[image]
[image]

For a more complicated case,
for the image on the left, The results should look like:

[image]
[image]

I was hoping Mathematica will have some built-in function to full fill the result.
I saw a demonstration project with similar function. But the shapes are built in also. I need to process some of my own image. And retrieve the original image from the spectrum image.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Check this - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29203/calculate-the-2d-fourier-transform-of-an-image

Comment: Take a look at the second answer and the second way there: [shift zero frequency to the center of a Fourier Transform?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100342/5478)