# How to perform local Fourier Transform of an image?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

Consider an image (`img`) as

[image]

A nice explanation of the Fourier transform of an image can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29203/calculate-the-2d-fourier-transform-of-an-image). However, I want to perform the Fourier transform locally. For example,

```
{w,h} = ImageDimensions[img];
imgparts = ImagePartition[img,{w/8,h/8}];
```

This will give me `64` image parts and I can apply Fourier transform on each image part and assemble them. However, this is computationally very expensive.

Is there any better and faster way (*maybe applying the Fourier transform only once*) to do it?

Comment: Is what you're trying to do not just some variation of wavelet analysis? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Wavelets.html

Comment: @SjoerdSmit In some sense. But I think, there are some fundamental differences. See this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=958567

Comment: Well, your partitioning of the image is pretty much equivalent to multiplying the image with 64 different masks. Multiplying in real space = convolution in Fourier space, so what you could do is compute the FT of the image and then perform convolutions of this FT with the FTs of the masks (which should be very simple).

Comment: Furthermore: `Map[ImagePeriodogram, imgparts, {2}]` and `dat = Map[Fourier@*ImageData, imgparts, {2}];` evaluates really fast for me on your example. How many transforms do you plan to do? I don't really see how this is operation is computationally prohibitive.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks. You are right.