# Plotting Fourier Image of 2D function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have function of two variables which was calculated numerically for grid `{x,y}`. Then I calculate numerical Fourier trasform of my function and obtain array of Fourier transform values. How can I find the array `{u,v,f[u,v]}`, where `u` and `v` Fourier coordinates and `f[u,v]` is obtained values of Fourier transform, i.e. how can I create frequency array `{u,v}`?

Comment: there are examples finding 2D Fourier in [calculate-the-2d-fourier-transform-of-an-image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29203/calculate-the-2d-fourier-transform-of-an-image/) I am assuming that is what you want. frequency and phase plot of 2D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your data in a 2D array form, but I've also shown how to convert a flat list to this form. You can use `ImagePeriodogram` to get the image, or use `Fourier` directly, or use `ImagePeriodogramArray` to get the image 2D array data:

```
(* make up some fake data in 2D grid form *)
f[x_, y_] := Sin[4 π x y^2] - y*Cos[6 π x]
data = Table[f[x, y], {y, 0, 1, .01}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];

ArrayPlot[data]

ft = Fourier[data]; (* note you may want to look into FourierParameters *)
(* to get ft in a flat list of {u,v,ft} where u,v are integers we can do: *)
ftflat = Flatten[MapIndexed[Append[#2,#1],ft,{2}],1];

(* see also ImagePeriodogramArray *)
ImagePeriodogram[Image@data]

(* if your data are in a flat list of the form {{x,y,f[x,y]}, {x,y,f[x,y]}, ... } *)
(* make up some fake data first *)
dataFlat = Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {y, 0, 1, .01}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}], 1];
(* convert dataFlat to the appropriate 2D array form  *)
dataConverted = Map[Last, GatherBy[dataFlat, #[[2]] &], {2}];
ArrayPlot[dataConverted]
ImagePeriodogram[Image@dataConverted]
```

[image: fourier image]

See also `FourierDCT` if you want a discrete cosine transform:

```
MatrixPlot[FourierDCT[data], ImageSize -> Medium]
```